# decompress string using 7-zip

Tags: 7zip

Is there a 7z command that decompress a string instead of a file?

I want to implement it in a c++ program so that it reads a file, edits it and try to decompress it

Thank you

Comment: Your C++ program will probably need to decompress the file, edit the decompressed copy, save it, and then compress it again.

Comment: If I save it, I'll waste a precious time, also I'm doing 2^32 decompression in less than 600s

Answer (score 0):

I know its no direct solution but it could help, look at this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/LZMA%20SDK/lzma920.tar.bz2/download